# Update value on table cell click

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a table I want users to be able to update on the fly (but can't use the Editable Table plugin, as I have other values I need to send with the form).

I want to show a form within the table cell once they click the cell. I've got as far to allow them to click the cell (and show the form), but they can't click the new textbox because it then they've clicked the table cell again.

Here's my JQuery:

```
$(function(){
// clicking on a TD cell
$('td').click(function(){
    // check that it's a valid cell
    if($(this).attr('employee').length > 0){;
        // is it an active shift?
        if($(this).attr('activeshift') == 1){
            // yes
        }else{
            // no - we show the form
            var form = '<form class="add_shift" id="add_shift"> \
                    <input type="text" name="shift" /> \
                    <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="' + $(this).attr('employee') + '" /> \
                    <input type="hidden" name="day" value="' + $(this).attr('day') + '" /> \
                    <input type="hidden" name="current_week" value="' + $(this).attr('current_week') + '" /> \
                    <br /> \
                    <small>Ex: 09:00 - 17:00 or 22:00 - 06:00</small> \
                </form>';
            // update content
            $(this).html(form);
        }
    }
});
```

});

Here's a sample cell:

```
<td employee="10" day="3" current_week=1" activeshift=""></td>
```

How do I allow the user to click the input within the cell?

And is there any way to remove the contents if they click away from the cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These all look like custom attributes, they should be prefixed with `data-` to pass validation.

Comment: actually, you can add you own custom attributes, you just need to specify them in your doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery .off()

```
$('td').click(function(){
   $(this).off('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fG35u/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use stopPropagation method:

```
$('td').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation()
// rest of your code here
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I think also [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). Then you can also use `if (e.isDefaultPrevented())` on other callbacks.

Comment: you're right, since the td doesn't have any default behaviour hooked to 'click' event, you can use preventDefault() as well